# Shoryuken taking very long to enqueue jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob, shoryuken

We are trying to switch to shoryuken as our ActiveJob backend. But while testing we found that there is a lot of latency while trying to enqueue a job.

this was the code which was written to test the latency.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    def self.tryFunc()
        puts Time.now
        SecondJob.perform_later('message')
        puts Time.now
    end
end
```

and got these results to this

```
023-07-24 13:09:26 +0530
Enqueued SecondJob (Job ID: 276b1b36-81e2-4a70-99c7-4708d18f1610) to Shoryuken(test-queue) with arguments: "message"
2023-07-24 13:09:31 +0530
```

is it the latency which is generally observed with Shoryuken or there could be other reasons to this delay?

Answer (score 0):

As `shoryuken` sends a message to third-party service `SQS`, some latency is expected.